# assigning a $scope variable to a normal variable

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to do a simple program with Angular JS/Ionic that will check the 2 scope variables assigned from two different templates ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/oIA5O47ldx7tbg8fH4ZJ))

```
.controller('personCtrl', function($scope , $rootScope) {    

    $scope.user = "";
    $scope.pass = "";
    $rootScope.reguser = "";
    $rootScope.regpass = "";
    $scope.url = "";

    $rootScope.regusername = function() {
        return $rootScope.reguser;
    };
    $rootScope.regpassword = function() {
        return $rootScope.regpass;
    };

    $scope.username = function() {
        return $scope.user;
    };
    $scope.password = function() {
        return $scope.pass;
    };

    $scope.check = function() {

        if ($scope.reguser == $scope.user && $scope.regpass == $scope.pass) {
            $scope.url = "googlemaps.html";
        }
    };
})
```

I tried $rootscope because I thought that it wouldt return the value, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you assign it to $rootScope first on the previous page? Like;
$rootScope.blabla= $scope.blabla

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is expected and what is happening

Comment: the check function will do the following , after the user makes an account with new user (reguser) and new pass (regpass) , the function will check if the login inputs are the same as the registed ones ( user=reguser & pass = regpass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in the previous question, I am not 100% sure about what you are asking. However, it looks like you are trying to find some sort of communication among controllers.

For this type of communication, you should use $broadcast from one controller and $on in the other controller:

1. Use a $watcher to detect the changes in the variable within the first controller,
2. Every time there is a change in the variable, send an event with $broadcast,
3. In the second controller, listen for the event with $on,
4. In the callback function within the $on at the second controller, update your variable in the $scope for this controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this might help!! , please help me know how to use these , i really dont know how to use $watcher $broadcast $on , also i should do 2 controllers right ?

Comment: First of all, start by explaining a little better your problem: what do you mean with "two different templates"?

Comment: ok , so in ionic they are called templates , but basically its an html page, ex: signup.html and login.html

Comment: Ok, but what do you want to do? I go to your plunker and I can see that you have a login HTML dialog. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: so these are the steps i want : 1- the user will register a new name and password , 2-the user will use the same user and password to login , it shouldnt login if they are not the same , hence the check function.

Comment: Ok, that's all a single controller, you do not have any necessity for trying to do what you were originally proposing. You only need 1 controller with 2 $scope variables, one for the name and another for the password. All you need to do is to call a function from within the "click" event on the button "register" or on the button "login".

Comment: what will the ng-click event do in this case?

Comment: It'll detect the click on the button and execute the function that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by your question, but I think you are asking how you can share assignments to $scope variables across templates.  I'm not sure how ionic works, but I'm pretty sure this can't be done in AngularJS since when each template renders, the personController gets re-initialized.

There's a couple of problems with your app:

1. Your "Create account" should have it's own controller and the "Sign in" page should have another controller.
2. With that corrected, the *correct* way to share variables across controllers (not templates) is to use Angular Services.

I won't go into detail about how to do that, I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I would also ask, why are you creating a function that the only things it does is return a value? Just use the value!!!

Comment: well , as i said i only have knowledge in java but not in angularjs , although i think this is what i need,  i have no idea wt Angular services are , could you please tell me ?

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki , yes i know , but when I am facing a problem i always try to fix it using any means before googling the problem , or asking someone.